# Print colored log of PVS-Studio analysis in Linux terminal

Tags: pvs-studio

I'm trying to integrate PVS-Studio analysis into CI for my homework. Everything seems to work fine except log printing; I want warnings to be colored or highlighted in some other way.

The best I could think of is to use plog-converter to output in html format and then use `elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 1` to output that in terminal but it looks kinda weird.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to modify the source of the `plog-converter`. The source code of the utility is published on [GitHub](https://github.com/viva64/plog-converter) so that users can expand the functionality for their tasks.

Comment: Oh dear, that's a bit extreme.

Answer (score 0):

Since `plog-converter` can't do it out of the box and modifying its source code is a bit extreme, I decided to highlight output myself.

After a bit of a fiddling with syntax highlighting in terminal I found out that the simplest way is just using `grep` kinda like this:

```
plog-converter -t errorfile project.log | \
 GREP_COLOR='01;31' grep -E --color=always 'error:|$' | \
 GREP_COLOR='01;33' grep -E --color=always 'warning:|$'
```

I suppose `errorfile` format should only containt "errors" and "warning" so this colorizes just these two words with two different colors